# Inline Enclosures in Wicket 6.17

Tags: wicket-6

I'm just trying to use wickets inline-enclosure functionality to toggle visibility of a block in ajax calls. I did exactly what is described here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3422

The only difference is, that I'm in a context of wicket:extend and wichet:child, so that my auto generated inline-enclosure is direct child of also auto-generated wicket:extend component.

There was a known bug with this in version 1.5:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3947

I'm using version 6.17 and I'm still having that problem. I can fix it by introducing a dummy container. That solution is suggested as a workaround in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-3947. That bug was fixed more than three years ago.

My question is: Is there anyone having the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The ticket is closed as a **duplicate** of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-4874, which is fixed in Wicket 7.0.0-M1.